# webservices using plist

Tags: objective-c, xcode, plist

I've been using `NSXMLParser` for parsing xml and was successful in launching apps ... Recently I'm facing problems with xml ... Since xml is heavy weight. It increases the memory over head ... I'm planning to shift to plist(since it reduces the memory overhead considerably). And have no idea where to begin with ... I've searched all through the net and was not successful could u guys gimme me a sample code or even a working url containing a plist ... Is more than enough ... I'd be so grateful if u guys could help me out.

Comment: But plist *is* XML (unless you mean the binary format).

Comment: @joe:yup i mean the stuff in binary format...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `CWXMLTranslator` from https://github.com/jayway/CWFoundation for easy translation from XML to domain object.

Assume you have this domain class:

```
@interface Book : NSObject {
}
@property(copy) NSString* author;
@property(copy) NSString* title;
@end
```

And this XML:

```
<books>
  <book>
    <author>James Joyce</author>
    <title>Ulysses</title>
  </book>
  <!-- MORE BOOKS HERE -->
</book>
```

You only need to define a translation file, name it `Book.xmltranslation`, and add this:

```
book +> @root : Book {
   author >> author;
   title >> title;
}
```

That would then be used to fetch and trabnslate the XML fromt he server into live instances of your `Book` class like this:

```
NSArray* books = [CWXMLTranslator translateContentsOfURL:url
                                    withTranslationNamed:@"Book"
                                                delegate:nil
                                                   error:NULL];
```

This is the easiest usecase available, the translation DSL can even be written inline if you want. The `CWXMLTranslator` support much more complex operations also, like type convertions to dates, URLs, numbers, etc. As well as nested types, and direct translation to Core Data managed objects.

The CWFoundation project contains all documentation you need, and a sample project that parses RSS feeds.

Comment: dude thanks for ur effort ..but the think is my team has already decided to go for binary plist.....where php tags are gonna get stripped and the data will be put in plist...and my job is to pull the content...higher ups have decided wid dis idea ..neither me nor the php team hav no idea where to start..do u hav any clue where to begin

Comment: @kingston - I got the impression that binary plists was your call from the question? Apple has documented the plist format, hidden as comment in this file http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550/CFBinaryPList.c

Comment: thanks..but dis looks little complex....a woking url containing a binary plist file is more than enough for me to begin wid...

Comment: @kingston - You can create your own binary plist with Xcode. Just select the binary type from the info panel, and save.

Answer (score 2):

if you have control over the format of the data, have you considered using JSON instead?

Comment: @niselbot:i wud consider going for json but...higher ups finalized to go for plist....its like dis the php team is  gonna remove the php tags and put the data in plist which then placed in mysql.....my job  is to access the url and pull the url cotent...php team and myself hav no idea where to begin....is it anyway possbile to have a woking plist url..with a sample code

Comment: I still say go with JSON, especially to store in your database. In any case, look at `[ NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error: ]` as a start. You could also try RestKit or ASIHTTPRequest if you want something more full featured. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Modern plists *are* XML: [Property Lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_list). It's possible to use and create binary plists, but they're just a form of binary XML. That can in turn mean some reduction in overhead, but at the cost of readability. [JSON](http://www.json.org/) can be smaller than equivalent XML, though not always.

Leaving all that aside, plists tend to be *more* verbose than equivalent XML. Compare the XML:

```
<book>
    <author>James Joyce</author>
    <title>Ulysses</title>
</book>
```

with an equivalent plist:

```
<dict>
    <key>author</key>
    <string>James Joyce</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>Ulysses</string>
</dict>
```

Comment: cud u gimme a working url that contains a plist placed in a remote server...thanks again